# Android: move app to sd (totally)

Tags: android, apk, sd-card

How can I let the user move an app to SD card, but totally?
I've used  `android:installLocation="auto"` in the android manifest, but it seems that it not move the entire app, only a piece.
Can you explain me how to let it move totally?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7450250/if-my-apps-installed-on-the-sd-card-is-the-private-data-there-too/7450369#7450369

Comment: Accept more answers to your previous questions.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way you can move app "totally" to the external storage. What you are using is your best possible bet. If your app consumes lot of memory due to data such media content etc or user created media. Write code which uses the external storage to store such data.